# Image and logo recognition

Tags: ios, image, frameworks, libraries, image-recognition

I need to achieve this goal : recognize a specific logo painted on a wall with the camera of the iPhone. I'd like to have a sort of database with N logos that the app should be able to recognize. Could you suggest me some useful libraries (premium or free) designed to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the Watson Visual Recognition API for this task.  You could train a custom classifier for each of the logos you want to recognize.  There is a demo here:  https://visual-recognition-demo.mybluemix.net/train and docs here: https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/visual-recognition/

Pricing info is here - https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/visual-recognition.html#pricing-block (there is a free plan)